# Wrapping only the visible content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ll2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rc_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rc_flag"
        android:contentDescription="@string/view_only_content_description"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/view_only_event_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/view_only_content_description"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_event_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_content_description"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and through the java code I play with the visibility of this images and image buttons:

> - @+id/rc_icon
> - @+id/view_only_event_button
> - @+id/delete_event_button

I want the buttons to be close to one another and near the far end of the view.
The problem is that right now when turning a button invisible, it's location still remains empty on the screen.

I was hopping the **@+id/ll2** layout wrap_content width would change according to the visibility of it's sons.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here instead of **invisible** you should use **gone** that's it.

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

change it to

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

The **gone** value removes the space occupied as well as view it's self from parent view and **invisible** makes them hidden but space occupied remains intact.

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html)

Answer (score 1):

to make button not occupied layout when invisible you should set the visibility to `gone` (`View.GONE`) instead, not `invisible`

Answer (score 1):

you need to make your view visibility GONE instead of INVISIBLE like this:-

i am using your code , check this out

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ll2">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rc_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_rc_flag"
    android:contentDescription="@string/view_only_content_description"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/view_only_event_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/view_only_content_description"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/delete_event_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_content_description"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```